# Multiple awk pipes leads to infinite loop

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to take a logfile which contains information about my simulation runs and do something with it.
Inside the logfile multiple output designations are logged, such as

> "output1.dat did something
>
> output2.dat did something else "

Now I want to get those names, as inside those files output1 and output2 more data is written which I want to operate on.

If I do

```
awk 'BEGIN{cnt=0} {cnt++} (cnt==100){print($1)}' output1.dat
```

then I get what I want. But I want a list of files to be passed to this awk, so that I don't have to type the name of output1.dat, via

```
grep 'stuff.*requirements' logfile_for_all_outputs.log | tail -n 10 | awk '{print($4)}' | awk '{print($1)}'
```

the second-last awk is filtering out the list of filenames, i.e. the output from the second-last awk is

> output1.dat
> output2.dat
> output3.dat
> ...

and I assumed it would send the files individually to the last awk, in order to be processed. However what I get is just an endless indirection, and $1 in the last awk is just the same list.

It would be great if someone could help clarifying what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Why did you assume that? Why would the last `awk` process its input differently from the previous `awk`? Filenames come from the command line arguments, not stdin.

Comment: You can use `xargs` to convert standard input into command-line arguments. So change the last `awk` to `xargs awk`

Comment: @Barmar: To me that looks like a difference, not like the same input processing... but thank you for the hint, now it works as intended. I'll try to figure out what was wrong in my reasoning. Feel free to post an answer that I can accept.

Comment: Instead of `awk 'BEGIN{cnt=0} {cnt++} (cnt==100){print($1)}' file` try `awk 'FNR==100' file`. And, as suggested by @Barmar, use `xargs` to pass all file names to the **same** `awk` command.

Comment: `grep 'stuff.*requirements' logfile_for_all_outputs.log` would produce no output from the sample input you've shown us. You can probably do everything you want with just 1 awk script, no need for pipes and multiple tools, so please create and post a [mcve] so we can help you. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

> want a list of files to be passed to this awk

GNU `AWK` can cope with more than one file, consider following simple example

```
awk '//' file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

will just concatenate `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` and `file3.txt`, if you wish to take action before or after every file [`BEGINFILE/ENDFILE`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/BEGINFILE_002fENDFILE.html) might come handy. In this case adjusting your code yields

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{cnt=0} {cnt++} (cnt==100){print($1)}' output1.dat output2.dat
```

however I want to note your code is very wordy way to instruct GNU `AWK` to print 1st column of 100th line, which might be written more concisely as

```
awk 'FNR==100{print $1}' output1.dat output2.dat
```

If you wish to know more about FNR read [8 Powerful Awk Built-in Variables – FS, OFS, RS, ORS, NR, NF, FILENAME, FNR](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/01/8-powerful-awk-built-in-variables-fs-ofs-rs-ors-nr-nf-filename-fnr/)